# How to use firebase auth and firestore so that users can't access other users' data by modifying the app's code?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I used firebase for auth in my application, after i got a user token and user email name.

And i access to the firestore to get user data by user email logged, i can get all data of user by user email

Struct of my firestore:

```
 - email_1:
   + data_1
 - email_2:
   + data_2
```

A big problem is anyone got my source code, they can login with their email, then do hardcode another email in source code and get data from firestore, therefore they can access any data in firestore. My question, how can an isolation be achieved?

Comment: I suggest learning about security rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using Firebase authentication you should use [Firebase Authentication with Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth?authuser=0).

With your Firestore structure, you should write some rules that restrict access to a user document based on the user's email (the email associated to the user account in Firebase Authentication and that corresponds, if I am not mistaken, to the email in your structure).

For example, if the documents are in a `users` collection, you could protect them with a read access right as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userEmail} {
      allow read: if request.auth.email == userEmail;
      allow write: ....
    }
  }
}
```

As detailed in the doc item referred above, the `auth.token` variable contains different values, like `email`, `email_verified`, etc.

You should study the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules?authuser=0) in order to adapt the Security Rules to your exact needs. It is also highly recommended to watch the official video about Security Rules for Firestore: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw